# FLTK 2.0 build and demo for circa-2011 code base for VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, fltk

I discovered a program that may meet some needs; the source is available on sourceforge but the dependency list was lacking sufficient detail. I've managed to track down (most) of them and selected the versions based upon the release date of the software. The goal is to get the code to compile as faithfully as it initially did back in 2011, *then* worry about upgrading/fixing/migrating to newer libraries.

One package, FLTK, is using the abandoned 2.0 version. I found two different versions. The project files included were 'one way upgraded' to MS2019. Many properties and links needed to be fixed.

I'm attempting to compile the test 'cubeview' program, and end up with 37 unresolved dependencies.

As below, I've gone into the project, properties, configuration prope

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 37 unresolved externals CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\Debug\CubeView.exe    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall fltk::Widget::find(class fltk::AssociationType const &,void *)const " (?find@Widget@fltk@@QBE_NABVAssociationType@2@PAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall fltk::Widget::add_shortcut(unsigned int)" (?add_shortcut@Widget@fltk@@QAE_NI@Z)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\ShortcutAssignment.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall fltk::Widget::remove(class fltk::AssociationType const &,void *)" (?remove@Widget@fltk@@QAE_NABVAssociationType@2@PAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall fltk::Widget::remove_shortcut(unsigned int)" (?remove_shortcut@Widget@fltk@@QAE_NI@Z)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\ShortcutAssignment.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void * __thiscall fltk::Widget::foreach(class fltk::AssociationType const &,class fltk::AssociationFunctor &)const " (?foreach@Widget@fltk@@QBEPAXABVAssociationType@2@AAVAssociationFunctor@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall fltk::Widget::test_shortcut(bool)const " (?test_shortcut@Widget@fltk@@QBE_N_N@Z) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\ShortcutAssignment.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void * __thiscall fltk::Widget::get(class fltk::AssociationType const &)const " (?get@Widget@fltk@@QBEPAXABVAssociationType@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall fltk::Widget::shortcut(void)const " (?shortcut@Widget@fltk@@QBEIXZ)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\ShortcutAssignment.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall fltk::Widget::add(class fltk::AssociationType const &,void *)" (?add@Widget@fltk@@QAEXABVAssociationType@2@PAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall fltk::Widget::add_shortcut(unsigned int)" (?add_shortcut@Widget@fltk@@QAE_NI@Z)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\ShortcutAssignment.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall fltk::Widget::set(class fltk::AssociationType const &,void *)" (?set@Widget@fltk@@QAEXABVAssociationType@2@PAX@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall fltk::Widget::remove_shortcuts(void)" (?remove_shortcuts@Widget@fltk@@QAEXXZ) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\ShortcutAssignment.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl fltk::foreach(class fltk::AssociationType const *,class fltk::Widget const *,class fltk::AssociationFunctor &)" (?foreach@fltk@@YAPAXPBVAssociationType@1@PBVWidget@1@AAVAssociationFunctor@1@@Z) referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl fltk::foreachShortcut(class fltk::Widget const *,class fltk::ShortcutFunctor &)" (?foreachShortcut@fltk@@YAIPBVWidget@1@AAVShortcutFunctor@1@@Z)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\ShortcutAssignment.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl delete_associations_for(class fltk::Widget *)" (?delete_associations_for@@YAXPAVWidget@fltk@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall fltk::Widget::~Widget(void)" (??1Widget@fltk@@UAE@XZ)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\Widget.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WSAAsyncSelect@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl fltk::add_fd(int,int,void (__cdecl*)(int,void *),void *)" (?add_fd@fltk@@YAXHHP6AXHPAX@Z0@Z) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\run.obj   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glBegin@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glBlendFunc@8 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor3f@12 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor4f@16 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glCopyPixels@20 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glDisable@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawBuffer@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)    CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnable@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnd@0 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glFlush@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__glOrtho@48    CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glOrtho@48 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glPopMatrix@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glPushMatrix@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glRasterPos2i@8 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glReadBuffer@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)    CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glRotatef@16 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glScalef@12 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)    CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glShadeModel@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)    CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glTranslatef@12 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)    CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertex3fv@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__glViewport@16 CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glViewport@16 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\CubeView.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__wglCreateContext@4 referenced in function "struct HGLRC__ * __cdecl fltk::create_gl_context(class fltk::Window const *,class fltk::GlChoice const *,int)" (?create_gl_context@fltk@@YAPAUHGLRC__@@PBVWindow@1@PBVGlChoice@1@H@Z)  CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__wglCreateLayerContext@8 referenced in function "struct HGLRC__ * __cdecl fltk::create_gl_context(class fltk::Window const *,class fltk::GlChoice const *,int)" (?create_gl_context@fltk@@YAPAUHGLRC__@@PBVWindow@1@PBVGlChoice@1@H@Z) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__wglDeleteContext@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl fltk::delete_gl_context(struct HGLRC__ *)" (?delete_gl_context@fltk@@YAXPAUHGLRC__@@@Z)   CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__wglMakeCurrent@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl fltk::no_gl_context(void)" (?no_gl_context@fltk@@YAXXZ) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__wglShareLists@8 referenced in function "struct HGLRC__ * __cdecl fltk::create_gl_context(class fltk::Window const *,class fltk::GlChoice const *,int)" (?create_gl_context@fltk@@YAPAUHGLRC__@@PBVWindow@1@PBVGlChoice@1@H@Z) CubeView    D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj)   1
```

Another 'output' portion that I failed to include:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: fltk, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Apps\MSBuild\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(445,5): warning MSB8004: Output Directory does not end with a trailing slash.  This build instance will add the slash as it is required to allow proper evaluation of the Output Directory.
1>C:\Apps\MSBuild\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(459,5): warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (Debug\) contains files shared from another project (boxtype.vcxproj, checkers.vcxproj, color_chooser.vcxproj, CubeView.vcxproj, cursor.vcxproj, demo.vcxproj, editor.vcxproj, file_chooser.vcxproj, fltkdll.vcxproj, fltk_images.vcxproj, fltk_opengl.vcxproj, fonts.vcxproj, hello.vcxproj, image.vcxproj, input.vcxproj, label.vcxproj, libjpeg.vcxproj, libpng.vcxproj, pack.vcxproj, qubix.vcxproj, tile.vcxproj, zlib.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.
1>C:\Apps\MSBuild\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1455,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\..\..\lib\fltk.lib) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\lib\fltk2d.lib). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).
1>C:\Apps\MSBuild\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1457,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(fltk) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (fltk2d). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).
1>fltk.lib.vcxproj -> D:\CodeProjects\fltk-2.0.x-master\fltk-2.0.x-master\ide\vcnet\..\..\lib\fltk.lib
1>Done building project "fltk.lib.vcxproj".
2>------ Build started: Project: CubeView, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>C:\Apps\MSBuild\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(459,5): warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (.\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (boxtype.vcxproj, checkers.vcxproj, color_chooser.vcxproj, cursor.vcxproj, demo.vcxproj, editor.vcxproj, file_chooser.vcxproj, fltk.vcxproj, fltkdll.vcxproj, fltk_images.vcxproj, fltk_opengl.vcxproj, fonts.vcxproj, hello.vcxproj, image.vcxproj, input.vcxproj, label.vcxproj, libjpeg.vcxproj, libpng.vcxproj, pack.vcxproj, qubix.vcxproj, tile.vcxproj, zlib.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.
2>cl : command line warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
2>cl : command line warning D9007: '/Gm' requires '/Zi or /ZI'; option ignored
2>CubeMain.cxx
2>CubeView.cxx
2>CubeViewUI.cxx
2>Generating Code...
2>C:\Apps\MSBuild\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(445,5): warning MSB8004: Output Directory does not end with a trailing slash.  This build instance will add the slash as it is required to allow proper evaluation of the Output Directory.
2>C:\Apps\MSBuild\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(459,5): warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (Debug\) contains files shared from another project (boxtype.vcxproj, checkers.vcxproj, color_chooser.vcxproj, CubeView.vcxproj, cursor.vcxproj, demo.vcxproj, editor.vcxproj, file_chooser.vcxproj, fltk.vcxproj, fltkdll.vcxproj, fltk_images.vcxproj, fonts.vcxproj, hello.vcxproj, image.vcxproj, input.vcxproj, label.vcxproj, libjpeg.vcxproj, libpng.vcxproj, pack.vcxproj, qubix.vcxproj, tile.vcxproj, zlib.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.
2>Done building project "fltk_opengl.vcxproj".
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBegin@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBlendFunc@8 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor3f@12 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor4f@16 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnable@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnd@0 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glOrtho@48 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glOrtho@48
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glPopMatrix@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glPushMatrix@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glRotatef@16 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glScalef@12 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glShadeModel@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTranslatef@12 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertex3fv@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CubeView::drawCube(void)" (?drawCube@CubeView@@AAEXXZ)
2>CubeView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glViewport@16 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CubeView::draw(void)" (?draw@CubeView@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glViewport@16
2>run.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSAAsyncSelect@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl fltk::add_fd(int,int,void (__cdecl*)(int,void *),void *)" (?add_fd@fltk@@YAXHHP6AXHPAX@Z0@Z)
2>Widget.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl delete_associations_for(class fltk::Widget *)" (?delete_associations_for@@YAXPAVWidget@fltk@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall fltk::Widget::~Widget(void)" (??1Widget@fltk@@UAE@XZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glCopyPixels@20 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDisable@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawBuffer@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glFlush@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glRasterPos2i@8 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glReadBuffer@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall fltk::GlWindow::flush(void)" (?flush@GlWindow@fltk@@UAEXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglCreateContext@4 referenced in function "struct HGLRC__ * __cdecl fltk::create_gl_context(class fltk::Window const *,class fltk::GlChoice const *,int)" (?create_gl_context@fltk@@YAPAUHGLRC__@@PBVWindow@1@PBVGlChoice@1@H@Z)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglCreateLayerContext@8 referenced in function "struct HGLRC__ * __cdecl fltk::create_gl_context(class fltk::Window const *,class fltk::GlChoice const *,int)" (?create_gl_context@fltk@@YAPAUHGLRC__@@PBVWindow@1@PBVGlChoice@1@H@Z)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglDeleteContext@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl fltk::delete_gl_context(struct HGLRC__ *)" (?delete_gl_context@fltk@@YAXPAUHGLRC__@@@Z)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglMakeCurrent@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl fltk::no_gl_context(void)" (?no_gl_context@fltk@@YAXXZ)
2>fltk2_gld.lib(Fl_Gl_Choice.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglShareLists@8 referenced in function "struct HGLRC__ * __cdecl fltk::create_gl_context(class fltk::Window const *,class fltk::GlChoice const *,int)" (?create_gl_context@fltk@@YAPAUHGLRC__@@PBVWindow@1@PBVGlChoice@1@H@Z)
2>.\Debug\CubeView.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 30 unresolved externals
2>Done building project "CubeView.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `glViewport` ...  looks like you missed linking to opengl

Comment: Thank you; I added that library and it took care of several. Is there a better approach to doing this hack/patch/find/figure than what I'm doing? A friend here gave me some ideas; I'll take any more ideas too.

Comment: A bit of googling the error message usually helps.

Comment: `unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall fltk::Widget::add(...` means you are probably not linking to one or more fltk libraries.

Comment: Since I'm building the libraries, shouldn't it link them? Or is it because they're getting the 'd' debug build that they aren't being included? That's the last error (for now) until the next pop up while compiling....

Comment: You seem to be building an executable called `CubeView.exe` in the first set of errors. That is what I was talking about.

Comment: Ahhh- Yes, the fltk has the library, which built, and the executable, which didn't. Turns out the library had a declared extern, but the source file wasn't included in the project build. Once that was found (and all of the suggestions done to add libs) the executable built. I'm stoked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to add the Windows libraries to link.
I would start with adding these libraries to your linker command:
glu32.lib opengl32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib comctl32.lib

If you are still missing things start adding these libraries if you are not already.
kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib oleaut32.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

Comment: Oh wow- that resolved like 90% of them. I don't know how I missed that- I'd been reading the macro text. Now delete_associations and that might do it....

Comment: what is still missing?

Comment: Looks like you may also need:    Ws2_32.lib

Comment: Thank you. There was also a cpp file missing (widgetassociations) from the project; adding that into the project permitted it to build to completion, and I was able to see the cube demo.